# How do you make it so plots have a graph-paper like look to them in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I make it so if I plot something, the final graph looks like it's on graph paper?

Can a simple plot like this
[image]

have a graph paper background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to make the background a grid, just like on paper, you can use the matplotlib.pyplot.grid() method. You can find more information about it here:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html